# I have the following errors when building the project. here is the error

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

This is the app build.gradle file in my project. Any help will be appreciated

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.Senior"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
```

I would be very glad if anyone could help me fix this because I have been at this for the past 3 days. My app build.gradle file is what has been illustrated above. Can anyone please tell me what it is I am missing out and what should I do.

Comment: can you post build.gradle files?

Comment: i just posted the app.gradle file

Comment: Welcome Ekeks! The question's title doesn't state the actual problem (what error is it?), so it's probably best to edit it. Also, the error is nowhere to be found in your post, so you might want to add it there too.